# Не могу подключиться к postgres docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

В докере есть бд Postgres. Разворачиваю докер, пытаюсь подключиться к бд с помощью pgAdmin (потом и с помощью DataGrip), но подключиться не удается. В pgAdmin получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: Unable to connect to server]

Причем на другом компьютере проблем нет.
Файл .env:

```
POSTGRES_ROOT_USER=root
POSTGRES_ROOT_PASS=1234
POSTGRES_DATABASE=appdata
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    container_name: core-postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_ROOT_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_ROOT_PASS}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - databases:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
volumes:
  databases:
    driver: local
```